# Why don't landlords simply reduce the rent by an equivalent amount, instead of offering incentives like rent-free periods?

Tags: real-estate-leasing

"Incentives" like Free Rent Periods and Tenant Improvement Allowances feel roundabout, overkill, and circuitous. Why do Landlords take "the scenic route"? Presuppose you are leasing for 1 year at $60,000 USD/year.

### Question 1

Presuppose the landlord grants 1 month of free rent. $60K/12 = $5K. Therefore  you pay $(60 — 5)K  = $55K in your first year.

**1. On the lease, why doesn't Landlord just write your monthly rent as $55K WITHOUT any free rent period?** Why do Landlords over-complicate the lease? After quantifying the monthly rent at $60K/year, Landlord adds at least two more paragraphs, one paragraph defining the rent-free period and another quantifying it as  1 month?

### Question 2

Presuppose "the landlord has agreed to reimburse the tenant for $50,000 worth of construction costs.".  Presuppose that Landlord in fact spends $50K for construction costs. Then your costs over 1 year = $(60 — 50)K = $10K.

**2. On the lease, why doesn't Landlord simply write your monthly rent as $10K  WITHOUT any Tenant Improvement Allowance?** Why do Landlords over-complicate the lease? After quantifying the monthly rent at $60K/year, Landlord adds at least two more paragraphs, one paragraph defining the Tenant Improvement Allowance and another quantifying it as $50K?

Comment: Questions about laws should have jurisdiction. Presuppose you make an agreement that is legal in place A - why do governments over-complicate things to make it illegal in place B?

Comment: @littleadv This is not a legal question! I have seen free rent periods and Tenant Improvement Allowances in leases in Australia, Canada, USA, UK.

Comment: These are very different things though

Comment: Marketing!  People like discounts more than they like lower prices.  They also don’t like to see price increases, which would happen in the second year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving/starting a business is expensive, skipping rent on the first month you're in a new space or not having to shell out for customizing the space for your business up front can be a big help. It's not just about the total rent paid, but the timing of expenses.

Landlord's could be offering renovation incentive knowing that likely not all of it will be used, thereby increasing profits. Similarly, since many businesses would have to take on debt to afford renovations it is likely that the cost of the incentive is actually less than the amount of increased rent it can generate, but to know that you'd have to compare similar spaces without such an incentive.

Establishing a higher monthly rent, even if it is offset somewhat by incentives, gives you a better starting point for negotiating rent at renewal that likely includes less/no incentive. This is just psychological, people tend to focus on the monthly number and not think about discounting it for any incentives received previously.

Such incentives on residential leases are less common, but you will see waived or reduced fees/deposits/first month's rent from time to time. It's the same idea, paying a little extra each month is easier than coming up with a larger amount up front for many people.

Comment: "This is just psychological" - It might have legal implications, if the landlord's ability to raise rent is regulated.

Answer (score 3):

Tenant improvement allowance refers to commercial real estate. The reasoning here is that the commercial tenant would *have to* do certain improvements (=remodeling) to the property to suit their needs. As such, the landlord is willing to credit that spending towards the rent. However the landlord has no interest in lowering the actual rent, why would they?

Similarly, the incentives like "1st month free" don't reduce rent, they just skip a payment. If you stay in the unit for a year, you'll pay 11/12th of the contracted rent, but if you stay there three years - you'll pay 35/36th. So reducing the rent outright to 11/12th would not benefit the landlord, since the longer you stay the more it costs to the landlord, while the incentive is supposed to be a fixed amount.

Comment: thanks again. But I am still dumbfound. *"As such, the landlord is willing to credit that spending towards the rent."* OK. Then why not lower the Tenant's rent by the amount of that credit? *"but if you stay there three years - you'll pay 35/36th"* OK. Why not just lower the monthly  rent by (1 free rent month/36 months of tenancy)($60K/year × 3 years) = $5K?

Comment: @Guest you're comparing apples to oranges. The TIA and the incentive are one-time expense to the landlord while the rent is a recurring contractual obligation to the tenant. They're not interchangeable. The leases are often renewed (in some areas once you enter into a lease - you can stay in it forever, which is why I asked about jurisdiction). So the rent obligation is not termed, while the incentive is.

Comment: *"The TIA and the incentive are one-time expense to the landlord while the rent is a recurring contractual obligation to the tenant."* I agree. But I am merely focused on the monetary amounts, which are the same. I am afraid I am still dumbfound.

Comment: @Guest consider this: I promise to give you an apple every week, as long as you promise to return the first apple back to me. How many apples per week am I giving you?

Comment: @Guest You are giving me 1 apple/week. But how is this analogous? Landlord is NOT granting free rent to Tenant every month, as long as Tenant pays the previous month's rent!

Comment: @Guest exactly. So if I pay my landlord $X/mo rent and got 1 month free, I'm still paying $X/mo rent. Not sure what's confusing here.